# Renaming the front of the class attribute with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have old documents that still use font attributes awosome v3.2.1 that all classes have first name the icon. If I use the new version would be very inconvenient if I had to rename the class one by one manually. HTML markup:

```
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> Info</a>
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i> Settings</a>
```

How can the results as below

```
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-sign"></i> Info</a>
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>
```

Help from anyone would be invaluable

Comment: Can you show us some code you've tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried search and replace feature of your editor? I think search for "icon" replace with "fa fa" should work. Any good editor can do this.

Comment: Find and replace in a text editor across files seems like the best solution.... Doing it in the browser is a bad idea since you are going to cause flashing of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the classnames like this:

```js
var icons = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=icon]');
for (icon of icons){
  icon.classList.value = icon.classList.value.replace('icon-','fa fa-');
  console.log(icon.classList.value);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> Info</a>
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i> Settings</a>
```

- Select all the elements that have a classname starting with `"icon"`
- For...of loop to iterate each icon, and replace its classname with where `"icon-"` with `"fa fa-"`
- Optional `console.log`

I would still do it the @richb01 way: find & replace directly in the code editor, much cleaner.

Comment: I've just tried and succeeded @ yuriy636. It's practically like what I expected. Thank you for helping to give an accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

basically you can do it with jquery method `switchClass` like that

```
$("a i").each(function(item){
   $(item).switchClass( "icon-info-sign", "fa fa-info-sign" );
   $(item).switchClass( "icon-trash" , "fa fa-trash" );
   $(item).switchClass( "icon-cog", "fa fa-cog" );
}
```

Comment: It still requires me to write the name of the class one by one @ÖzgürErsil, in a lot of pages of documents I need to find the class name one by one in advance